# MYSQL - groupings

Tags: mysql

Given the following mysql result set:

```
 id      code       name               importance
'1234', 'ID-CS-B', 'Chocolate Sauce', '1',
'1122', 'ID-MC-A', 'Mint Choc Chip',  '5',
'5621', 'ID-MC-B', 'Mint Choc Chip',  '4',
'1221', 'ID-CS-A', 'Chocolate Sauce', '2',
'1212', 'ID-CS-C', 'Chocolate Sauce', '3',
```

There are two products here: Chocolate Sauce and Mint Choc Chip.  I would like to pull a single instance from each product based on the importance.

I want the most important Mint Choc Chip product and the most important chocolate sauce product using the column "importance": the higher the value the more important

Answer (score 3):

```
    SELECT x.*
      FROM my_table x
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT name, MAX(importance) max_importance FROM my_table GROUP BY name ) y
        ON y.name = x.name
       AND y.max_importance = x.importance;
```

Comment: Thanks! The table shown above is the result from a query: what would be the syntax for linking your query to this result set?

Comment: It depends on the complexity of the original query. The obvious answer is to replace each instance of 'my_table' with '(your_query)', but you may be able to do the whole thing (more efficiently) without nested subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well,

```
select b.name, max(a.importance)
from t b
left join t a
on b.id = a.id
group by b.name
;
```

Results:

```
NAME                MAX(A.IMPORTANCE)
Chocolate Sauce     3
Mint Choc Chip      5
```

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1644d/1)

Comment: @Johnathan let us know how your original query looks like. You may get better performance with this, however it based on what you are currently doing.